# How to add "Roboto" font in TinyMCE Advanced drop down menu in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, fonts, tinymce

What should I do? I searched in English, Spanish, Italian but found no useful guide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4nr6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Hello and sorry for my previous answer, I got the wrong topic.

In the **header.php** file of your child theme (if it does not exists, copy it from parent theme), you need to add the Roboto font just before the following line:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

So you need to copy the integration code of the Roboto font from google:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Source: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Roboto

Then, in the **functions.php** file you have to add a filter on 'tiny_mce_before_init' to add the Roboto font in the drop down of TinyMCE Advanced:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_custom_fonts' );
function mce_custom_fonts( $init ) {
    $theme_advanced_fonts = "Andale Mono=andale mono,times;" .
                            "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" .
                            "Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;" .
                            "Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;" .
                            "Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;" .
                            "Courier New=courier new,courier;" .
                            "Georgia=georgia,palatino;" .
                            "Helvetica=helvetica;" .
                            "Impact=impact,chicago;" .
                            "Roboto=Roboto, sans-serif;" . /* This is regular Roboto font */
                            "Symbol=symbol;" .
                            "Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" .
                            "Terminal=terminal,monaco;" .
                            "Times New Roman=times new roman,times;" .
                            "Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;" .
                            "Verdana=verdana,geneva;" .
                            "Webdings=webdings;" .
                            "Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats";
    $init['font_formats'] = $theme_advanced_fonts;
    return $init;
}
```

Then you can choose Roboto font in the [Drop Down Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVa09.png)

Please don't forget to upvote if this answer make you happy :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still haven't managed to add roboto to tinymce advanced. I copied your codes but it doesn't work, look: header -> https://ibb.co/FhJB6M3 and functions -> https://ibb.co/fvZYzMF why?

Comment: Are you using this plugin ?
https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

Comment: Exactly, yes. I use this plugin

Comment: So it should work because I tested it before posting it.

You did create a child theme, created a file named functions.php?

Comment: No, I haven't created a child theme. I'm a newbie on wordpress, could you explain me how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't explain it better than the official wordpress documentation, so I refer you to it: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: I created the child theme but the roboto font does not add to the dropdown.  What do you think if I first create a tinymce_custom_editor.css file and upload it to my theme's CSS folder?